# Unable To Create album to Facebook group using php sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am using php sdk for creating album in a group ,publish_actions and user_managed_groups permissions are already given as these are required according to the graph api docx:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/albums
but i am unable to create album getting error: 
**(#10) Application does not have permission for this action**

If someone can help it will be really appriciated.

Comment: i am not sure, but i believe it´s only possible to create albums in game groups, but not in real ones.

Comment: Hey! luschn ,thanks for your reply. . . according to the docx:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/albums
it seems possible :(

Comment: i know, but a lot of people asked for this already and the answer was always "it´s not possible".